# Play Framework: How to replace all the occurrence of a value in a JSON tree

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{ "id":"1234",
  "name" -> "joe",
  "tokens: [{
     "id":"1234",
     "id":"2345"
   }]
}
```

... I need to replace the value of all the `id`s by `xxxx` like this:

```
{ "id":"xxxx",
  "name" -> "joe",
  "tokens: [{
     "id":"xxxx",
     "id":"xxxx"
   }]
}
```

Let's start create the JSON tree:

```
val json = Json.obj(
  "id" -> "1234",
  "name" -> "joe",
  "tokens" -> Json.arr(
     Json.obj("id" -> "1234"),
     Json.obj("id" -> "2345")
  )
)

json: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"id":"1234","name":"joe","tokens":[{"id":"1234"},{"id":"2345"}]}
```

Then, getting all the `id`s is very simple:

```
 json \\ "id"

 res64: Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = List("1234", "1234", "2345")
```

Now, how do I replace the value of all the `id`s by `xxxx`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a nice way to do this with the standard Play JSON library, although I'd be happy to be proved wrong in that regard. You can however do it easily using the [play-json-zipper](https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-zipper) extensions:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.extensions._

val json = Json.obj(
  "id" -> "1234",
  "name" -> "joe",
  "tokens" -> Json.arr(
    Json.obj("id" -> "1234"),
    Json.obj("id" -> "2345")
  )
)

// Using `updateAll` we pattern match on a path (ignoring
// the existing value, as long as it's a string) and replace it
val transformed = json.updateAll {
  case (__ \ "id", JsString(_)) => JsString("xxxx")
}

// play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":"xxxx","name":"joe","tokens":[{"id":"xxxx"},{"id":"xxxx"}]}
```

To make that a re-usable function:

```
def replaceValue(json: JsValue, key: String, replacement: String) = json.updateAll {
  case (__ \ path, JsString(_)) if path == key => JsString(replacement)
}
```

The json-zipper extensions are still "experimental", but if you want to add them to your project add the following to your `project/Build.scala` appDependencies:

```
"play-json-zipper" %% "play-json-zipper" % "1.0"
```

and the following resolver:

```
"Mandubian repository releases" at "https://github.com/mandubian/mandubian-mvn/raw/master/releases/"
```

Comment: Tx, already tried... but I need to pass the key as parameter, and that case it doesn't work: def toXXXX(json: JsValue, key: String) = json.update {
  case ((_ \ key), value) => JsString(value)
}

Comment: @j3d: Can you define "doesn't work"? I've added an example if the key and replacement value are both parameters. The code you posted in the comment looks wrong (you need to use `updateAll` and you're matching the existing value with the desired replacement.)

Comment: Gasp, yours works perfectly. The problem is that the real example is more complex. I've just posted a new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801071/how-to-replace-all-the-values-with-the-same-key-in-a-json-tree] - if not bored yet, you could give a quick look ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it isn't most efficient way to do it, but you can try to convert your JSON to an object copy it with new fields and then convert it back to json. Unfortunately currently I don't have environment to check the code, but it should be something like this:

```
case class MyId(id: String)
case class MyObject(id: String, name: String, tokens: List[MyId])

implicit val idFormat = Json.format[MyId]
implicit val objectFormat = Json.format[MyObject]

val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
val jsResult = Json.fromJson[MyObject](json)

val obj = jsResult match {
      case JsSuccess(s, _) => s
      case _ => throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected")
    }

val newObj = obj.copy(id = "xxxx")
val result = Json.toJson(newObj)
```