# How to replace all the values with the same key in a JSON tree

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Before storing any JSON document in MongoDB, I need to transform all the string `id`s in the document into BSON `id`s and, vice-versa, when reading any document from MongoDB, I need to transform all the BSON `id`s into string `id`. That said, given the following JSON...

```
{
  "id" : "52fe942b790000790079b7d0",
  "email" : "joe@domain.com",
  "username" : "joe",
  "subscriptions" : [
    {
      "accountId" : "72fe942b790000790079b755",
      "name" : "test 1",
      "isDefault" : true
    },
    {
      "accountId" : "72fe942b796850790079b743",
      "name" : "test 2",
      "isDefault" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

... I need to transform it as described here below before storing it in MongoDB...

```
{
  "_id" : {"$oid" : "52fe942b790000790079b7d0"},
  "email" : "joe@domain.com",
  "username" : "joe",
  "subscriptions" : [
    {
      "accountId" : {"$oid" : "72fe942b790000790079b755"},
      "name" : "test 1",
      "isDefault" : true
    },
    {
      "accountId" : {"$oid" : "72fe942b796850790079b743"},
      "name" : "test 2",
      "isDefault" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

... and of course I need to convert back all the BSON `id`s into string `id`s when reading the document from MongoDB.

Here below is the code I've tried to convert BSON `id`s into string `id`s (using the `JsZipper` library):

```
def toPublic(json: JsValue, key: String) = json.updateAllKeyNodes {
  case ((__ \ key), value) => (key -> value \ "$oid")
}
```

Given that this method does not transform `id` into `_id`, it doesn't work at all and always  returns `res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"accounts":null}`; on the other hand, if I hardcode the key like this...

```
def toPublic(json: JsValue) = json.updateAllKeyNodes {
  case ((__ \ "accountId"), value) => ("accountId" -> value \ "$oid")
}
```

... it works as expected and I get back the JSON in the second example. I'm a bit lost, so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using [play-json-zipper](https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-zipper) as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798632/285374).

Given the inconsistencies (id -> _id, etc) in your data I don't think it's going to be easy to handle this without some hard-coding:

Here's a start, which handles the case you've given in a to/from manner:

```
def toPublic(json: JsValue) = json.updateAllKeyNodes {
  case ((_ \ "_id"), value) => "id" -> value \ "$oid"
  case ((_ \ "accountId"), value) => "accountId" -> value \ "$oid"
}

def fromPublic(json: JsValue) = json.updateAllKeyNodes {
  case ((_ \ "id"), JsString(value)) => "_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> value)
  case ((_ \ "accountId"), JsString(value)) => "accountId" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> value)
}
```

You can probably abstract this a fair bit to handle your special cases more nicely. For instance you could apply it multiply with the to/from key rules as a map:

```
def fromPublicWithKeys(json: JsValue, keys: Map[String,String]): JsValue = {
  def fromPublic(json: JsValue, keys: (String,String)) = json.updateAllKeyNodes {
    case ((_ \ key), JsString(value)) if key == keys._1 => keys._2 -> Json.obj("$oid" -> value)
  }
  keys.foldLeft(json)(fromPublic)
}
```

Usage:

```
fromPublicWithKeys(stdJson, Map("id" -> "_id", "accountId" -> "accountId"))
// play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"_id":{"$oid":"52fe942b790000790079b7d0"},"email":"joe@domain.com","username":"joe","subscriptions":[{"accountId":{"$oid":"72fe942b790000790079b755"},"name":"test 1","isDefault":true},{"accountId":{"$oid":"72fe942b796850790079b743"},"name":"test 2","isDefault":false}]}
```

Note: one reason your first example doesn't work is that you're trying to pattern match the `key` value, but it's instead creating a new shadowed variable binding called `key` (something I **often** do wrong in Scala.) Instead you need to use a pattern match *guard*, like `case ((__ \ path), _) if path == key => ...`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much... you got me out of trouble :-) Just the last question: if I pass an internal JSON to fromPublic, no transformation occurs and I get the original JSON. That's correct. But if I pass a public JSON to toPublic, I get a transformed JSON with accountId set to null. If toPublic gets a public JSON as an input, it should return the input JSON withot transformation like fromPublic does. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @j3d: I'm tempted to say "don't do that" ;). But you could handle it with something like this, potentially: https://gist.github.com/mikesname/9027468

Comment: Thank you very much for your great support!